# Laravel 5 - Pre-Populate form using 'old'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a form input for editing an existing entry in a Laravel 5 app like this..

```
<input name="obj_email" type="text" value="{{$myobject->obj_email}}">
```

This works correctly and when the form loads it pre-populates the value, but if some form validation fails, when the page reloads it loses the email that I entered.

I tried to fix it by doing this..

```
<input name="obj_email" type="text" value="{{old('obj_email')}}">
```

This works and it now does not lose the value when validation fails But it does not pre-populate the form on initial load anymore.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a second parameter to the old() helper to supply a default value. So you can do something like:

```
<input name="obj_email" type="text" value="{{old('obj_email',$myobject->obj_email)}}">
```

So if the "old" value is available it will use that, otherwise it will use the default that you supply for the first time the form is loaded.

Here is the doc reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-old

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong, but `old()` will be null initially since there's reallly no "old" data. Try something like this:

```
<input name="obj_email" type="text" value="{{ old('obj_email')?: $myOjbect->obj_email }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic you need to implement.

If there is an `old('value')` put that value, else put `$object->value`.

this is how the code may look like

```
<input name="obj_email" type="text"
    value="old('obj_email') ? old('obj_email') : $myObject->my_email">
```